# $.post not working . no errors are shown

Tags: php

```
function confirm_reg(id){
    if(confirm("Are you sure want to complete")){
       $('#'+id).hide(500);
       $.post(
          'sample.php',
          {id6:id},
          function(data){
           alert(data);
          }
       );   
    }
}
```

**sample.php**

```
echo "something";
```

---

NO errors are showing in firebug console . even the hide function works . but posting is not working !

Comment: Try using the full web path to your file - `http://www.yoursite.com/path/to/sample.php`. You should also check your networks tab, it would've, most likely, thrown an error.

Comment: Is the sample.php located in the same directory of this js file

Comment: instead of alert, try `console.log`

Comment: check sample.php file location.. ?? your js and php files are in same folder??

Comment: and plz explain what do u mean, $.post not working, either not sending the request on server or not getting response from the server?

Comment: OP its very important to respond on queries. when u ask something.

Answer (score 0):

Try flollowing:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data, //Data to be sent to server.
    success: function(data) {
    },
    dataType: dataType //Type of data you are expecting from server such as xml, json, html, etc
});
```

Comment: what is data and what should be type?

Comment: data : Data to be sent to server. dataType : Type of data you are expecting from server such as xml, json, html, etc.